# How to position a block at the same height as another block in Trackmania Nations Forever's map editor?

Tags: trackmania-forever

I often want to position a block at the same height as another block in Trackmania Nations Forever's map editor. To do so I have to manually adjust the height before positioning the new block to make sure it is at the same height.

Is there any way to change the current height to be the same as a given block on the map?

The current height is different:

[image]

The current height is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rectangle button in the editor:

[image]